# 自然言語処理の前処理として、自然言語とコード部分を切り分けたい

Tags: python, 自然言語処理

自然言語とコード部分が混在しているテキストを、自然言語とコード部分に分割したいです。

GitHubのissueの分析を行っていますが、issueの本文内に自然言語とコードやログが混在していることが多々あります。
Markdown等を用いてあるissueでは該当箇所を分割することができます。しかし、コードやログ結果を直貼りしてある場合は切り分けが難しく困っています。
何かいい方法はありますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

**追記**

コード部分と自然言語が書き分けられてる場合は分割可能ですが、後者の例だと分割が難しく、分析データにノイズが多く含まれているのが現状です。

分割可能なissue例

- https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/579

分割が難しいissue例

- https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/318

Comment: 解析したいissue例とやってみたコードを提示したほうが回答しやすいかと思います

Comment: 目的の自然言語処理ではおそらく機械学習をなさるのだろうと思いますが、その場合、この前処理は学習部分で行うのでしょうか、それとも学習済みモデルを使って実際に処理する部分で行うのでしょうか？

Comment: 「切り分ける」という操作をもう少し具体的にしたいです。たとえばソースコードがブロックコードとしてしか存在しないのであれば話は多少簡単ですが、インラインコードまで考えるのであればそれ自身が自然言語の文の中で役割を持っている可能性があり、その後の自然言語処理でどのような処理を行いたいのかによって扱い方が変わってきそうです。質問文を [edit] して、どんな自然言語処理のためにどのような前処理をしたいのかを具体的にしてくださいませんでしょうか。

Comment: 前提の確認なのですが、機械学習等の教師データを得るという目的でしょうか？でしたら、逆に分離できてないものをそもそも使わないという方針もアリだと思います（マークダウンで指定してないissueは他の部分でも質が低いことが想定されるので）

Comment: @Liamovwv おっしゃる通りです。確かにそもそも学習データに含めないというのは手だと思います。しかし、対象データの数に不安があり、極力多くしたいなとは思っています。